# IS NOT NULL on as statement

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc

I have two tables called 'teacher' and 'courses'. Table 'teachers' has four columns i.e. teacher_id, teacher_name, teacher_work_hours and course_id. Table 'courses' has two columns i.e. course_id and course_name. I want to select two columns from table 'teacher' and count the number of instances in table 'courses' for which teacher.course_id = course.course_id. The query should discard the rows where the count(*) for table course is zero i.e. the the rows for which count(*) is zero should not show up in the resultset. How do I do that?
I have this query.

```
select t.teacher_name, t.teacher_work_hours, (select count(*) 
                     from course where course_id = t.course_id
                     having count(*) > 0) as COURSES 
from teacher t 
where teacher_work_hours > 5 
  AND COURSES IS NOT NULL
```

The query is incorrect as it doesn't let me put IS NOT NULL operator on COURSES.

Comment: How `ROLES IS NOT NULL` makes any sense here?

Comment: What are the fields available in xyz table? No condition... It is always have the same count...

Comment: Instead of showing your broken query and poor explanation would be best to give example data and desired results. Not really clear what you are trying to do with this approach.

Comment: in addition to showing your broken query*

Comment: You cannot use column aliases inside a `WHERE` clause. The only clause that allows the use of column aliases is the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

`ROLES` is a table rather than a column, and anyway it only appears within the subquery. Would this not make more sense? (This still won't work, because you can't use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, but it is closer to making sense.)

```
SELECT name, class, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM xyz
                     -- HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
                         -- Doesn't make sense without a GROUP BY
                     ) AS ROLES
FROM abc
WHERE class > 5
  AND ROLES IS NOT NULL
```

I don't think this is what you actually want to do, though, because the subquery doesn't depend upon the current row of `abc`. You probably need to change the query to use a join and a `GROUP BY` instead of a subquery.

Comment: First of all, you can't use column alias in WHERE clause. Second using having without group by and checking `ROLES IS NOT NULL` makes no sense

Comment: Though FYI, I didn't down voted, but `ROLES` will return the count (total count without any grouping). I don't understand, how checking `roles is not null` will achieve any benefit here.

Comment: You can't use column alias name in Where clause, and all query is nonsense, because count is not connected with primary table abc...

Comment: @MS: It's not an "answer", in the sense that it isn't a working solution. The answer doesn't contain a working solution; answers need not in general do so. The SQL code presented is intended to suggest an approach that, although it has a flaw, is closer to being along the correct lines. The true solution is to follow the suggestion and refactor the query to use a join and a group by.

Comment: @Justin, I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to add, because those are both things that are commented upon in the answer itself.

Comment: For your information I'd rather the reputation system didn't exist at all, because I think gamification systems are ridiculous and a poor way to run a community. At any rate, I do not regard this question as unclear, and so I see no reason not to answer it.

Comment: You continue to confuse the SQL in the answer with the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Query is not clear. But I just wanted to share the following query for your reference. Please do check the query whether it is useful...

```
SELECT class, ROLES.Total
FROM   abc 
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM xyz WHERE abc.class = xyz.class) ROLES
WHERE  class > 5
```